# How to display both output and value results in org mode for a source code block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have the following:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC lisp :results value 
  (dolist (x '(1 2 3))
    (print x))

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: NIL
```

I want my results block to contain both the output and the value for my source. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:results value` and `:results output` are collection options.
From the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html):

> Collection options specify the results. Choose one of the options; they are mutually exclusive.

So they are **mutually exclusive**.

If the evaluation takes only little time you can call the source block twice with different collection options:

```el
#+NAME: F
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output
(dolist (x '(1 2 3))
  (print x))
"Hello World"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: F
: 
: 1
: 
: 2
: 
: 3

#+CALL: F[:results value]()

#+RESULTS:
: Hello World
```

If the evaluation of the source block is costly you can redirect the output to the value of the block. I've written a macro `with-cons-value.stdout` for that purpose. If you encapsulate your lisp forms by that macro you get a `cons` with the last value of the lisp forms as `car` and the `stdout` string as `cdr`. If you need the macro multiple times you can move it from the source block to your init file.

```el
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value
(defmacro with-cons-value.stdout (&rest body)
  "Evaluate BODY like `progn'.
Return `cons' with value of BODY as `car' and
the standard output string as `cdr'."
  (declare (debug body))
  `(let ((old-stdout standard-output)
         stdout)
     (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (setq stdout (generate-new-buffer "stdout")
                 standard-output stdout)
           (cons
            (progn ,@body)
            (with-current-buffer stdout (buffer-string)))
           )
       (setq standard-output old-stdout)
       (kill-buffer stdout))))

(with-cons-value.stdout
 (dolist (x '(1 2 3))
   (print x))
 "Hello World")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: (Hello World . 
: 1
: 
: 2
: 
: 3
: )
```

Comment: The specified link does not work anymore. The current one (at the time of writing this comment, of course) is [this one](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html).

Comment: @applesoup Thanks for the hint. Answers here are collaborative work. If you detect a simple error like that one you can correct it yourself if you want.

Comment: and thanks for that hint as well. I'll simply change things like that next time.